# Ubuntu 22.04 RDR2 Can't play

Tags: 22.04

Hello I downloaded RDR2 on steam and I can't play it.

```
Error|
Game executable path not found. Please reinstall the game
```

(I reinstalled game like 5 times.)

```
Error|
Unable to launch Red Dead Redemption 2. If you continue to have problems launching the game, please verify the integrity of your game files via settings menu or contact Rockstar Games Customer Service at https://support.rockstargames.com. Code: 7002.1

RAM:16 GB|
GPU Driver:NVIDIA 535|
GPU:NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650|
CPU:Intel i5 10400f|
```